# Change specific label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can anyone tell me how to get the specific label in this case?

this is a loop so it always goes to the last item label.

I can pass the ScrolledText but cant pass the label, the label is lblspec, this (my_var_expected.set(textlabl)) works but only update the last label of the for loop

```
def checkval(e, spec0, spec1, spec2, spec3, spec4, spec5):
    e.widget.insert("1.0", PLACEHOLDER if e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c") == "" else "")
    reqlidst=(spec0, spec1, spec2, spec3, spec4, spec5)

    textlabl=""

    for x in reqlidst:
        x = x.replace("#", "")
        x = x.replace(" ", "")
        if len(x)>1:
            if x.upper() in e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c").upper():
                if len(textlabl)>1:
                    textlabl = textlabl+ x.replace(" ", "").upper() + "  " + html.unescape('&#x2714;')+"\n\n"
                else:
                    textlabl = x.replace(" ", "").upper() + "  " + html.unescape('&#x2714;')+"\n\n"
            else:
                if len(textlabl) > 1:
                    textlabl = textlabl+ x.replace(" ", "").lower() + "  " + html.unescape('&#x2718;')+"\n\n"
                else:
                    textlabl = x.replace(" ", "").lower() + "  " + html.unescape('&#x2718;')+"\n\n"

        my_var_expected.set(textlabl)<---- cant get this to update the correct label
        print(textlabl)


    for line in var_expect_result:
        if len(line)>1:
            x, y, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5 = line.split('<->')
            y_respexpt = (y + "\n\n" + y1 + "\n\n" + y2 + "\n\n" + y3 + "\n\n" + y4 + "\n\n" + y5).replace('##', '').strip()
            y_respexpt = y_respexpt.replace(' ', '').strip()


            my_var_expected = StringVar()
            my_var_expected.set(y_respexpt)

            kiblogbn = ScrolledText(frmbtn, name="frm_"+str(x), width=25, height=30,border=2,relief="solid")
            kiblogbn.grid(column=coll, row=2, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=25,sticky="W")
            PLACEHOLDER = 'Copy logs from Kibana and past them here.'
            kiblogbn.insert(END, PLACEHOLDER)
            kiblogbn.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: e.widget.delete("1.0", "end-1c") if e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c") == PLACEHOLDER else None)
            kiblogbn.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e, y=y, y1=y1, y2=y2, y3=y3, y4=y4, y5=y5: checkval(e, y, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5))

         
            lblspec = Label(frmbtn, textvariable=my_var_expected, justify='left', anchor=N)
            lblspec.grid(column=coll, row=6, rowspan=99, sticky=N, padx=20, pady=20)
```

Comment: Is `textlabl = textlabl, x.replace(" ", "").upper() + ":VALID:"` a string ? or a tuple ? and `x` is always the last item in `reqlidst`.

Comment: Its a string, already change my code.  x is the value from the reqlidst, for example:   reqlidst=one,word,to,rule,them,all

Comment: if you use one `StringVar` for all labels then obviously all the labels will have the same value, please provide a [mre], also you can simply do `def checkval(e, *args)` then you can simply use `args` as it will already be a tuple of however many values you have specified after the first argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way is to use an attribute of `kiblogbn` to save a reference of the variable `my_var_expected`:

```py
for line in var_expect_result:
    if len(line)>1:
        ...
        my_var_expected = StringVar()
        my_var_expected.set(y_respexpt)

        kiblogbn = ScrolledText(frmbtn, name="frm_"+str(x), width=25, height=30,border=2,relief="solid")
        kiblogbn.my_var_expected = my_var_expected # save reference of variable
        ...
```

Then use `e.widget.my_var_expected` inside `checkval()`:

```py
def checkval(e, spec0, spec1, spec2, spec3, spec4, spec5):
    ...
    for x in reqlidst:
        ...
        e.widget.my_var_expected.set(textlabl)
        print(textlabl)
```

Comment: thank you, didnt know that, thanks alot, it will come very in handy